# Python : How to rename the column name that changes with the unique value in other column?

Tags: python, pandas

```
data = {'pop': [2.0, 3.0, 4.0],'county':['jpy','jpy','jpy']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to change the column('pop') name dynamically with the unique value in other column. I do not want to hard code the column value. I'm trying something like below but it's throwing an error.

```
 value = df.county.unique()
 df.rename(columns={'pop': str(value)}, inplace=True)
```

Expected output:

```
df = jpy    county
    2.0     jpy
    3.0     jpy
    4.0     jpy
```

Comment: looks like you have answer in the question itself, could you explain further? like posting the error

Comment: I have multiple files with based on 'county'. in later program i have to merge all these files and populate the column name as 'county value'. For which everything is already set. I just need to rename like above method. How can I do it. Please suggest.

Comment: My understanding, you have county names in county column and value of counties in jpy. you need to create new empty columns for all the unique values in county then use apply method to map new column values to respective counties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with the given data you can use:

```
df.rename(columns={'pop': str(*value)}, inplace=True)
```

you will cast to `str` the only element from `value`

output:

[image]

also you can use:

```
df.rename(columns={'pop': list(value)[0]}, inplace=True)
```